# The relationship between function space embeddings and their respective inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $L^{p,\infty}$ be the weak $L^p$ space consisting of measurable functions $f$ satisfying
\begin{equation*} 
||f||_{p,\infty}:=\sup_{\rho}\rho\lambda (|f|>\rho)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty .
\end{equation*}

Given that we have the embedding $L^p(\mathbb{T}^n)\subset L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n)$ with $\mathbb{T}^n$ the $n-$dimensional torus, then how come this is equivalent to writing
\begin{equation*}
||\cdot||_{p,\infty}\leq ||\cdot||_p?
\end{equation*}
The inequality suggests that the $L^p$ norm is controlling the behaviour of the weak $L^p$ norm but does the embedding say that weak $L^p$ is controlling the behaviour of $L^p$? Why is the inequality not the other way around?

This is just an example, but I have seen this with many other inequalities and embeddings.

This may be trivial, but I just wanted some clarification. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your second and third questions, note that the inequality $\| \cdot\|_{p,\infty} \le \|\cdot\|_p$ leads to
$$ \|\cdot\|_p < \infty \implies \|\cdot\|_{p,\infty} < \infty$$
which in turn gives 
$$f \in L^p \implies f \in L^{p,\infty}$$ i.e., $L^p \subset L^{p,\infty}$. That is why the inequality seems backward from the containment.

---

How does the inequality arise from the containment? If $X \subset Y$ are Banach spaces and the identity $I : X \to Y$ is continuous, then there exists $C$ satisfying $\|f\|_Y \le C \|f\|_X$.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought it seemed a little counterintuitive when I first came across it and just wanted some clarification from others.